# Missing "List of response notifications..." in Microsoft Flow automation

Tags: power-automate, ms-forms

I am trying to create a simple automation of survey data into an excel spreadsheet. Based on other how-tos, it should be as simple as adding the form and workbook then mapping the fields from the form to the headers of the spreadsheet. Mine is only displaying "Response ID" when it should be displaying "List of response notifications..." I thought maybe it was due to me not being the original creator of the Microsoft Form, but I've tried on some I've created too with no luck. The "Apply to each" action does not work either, it does not show the "List" option. Anyone have an idea?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to have the Form/Survey in your "My Forms" section, it cannot just be shared. Now I have to figure out the non-question responses, i.e. name and timestamps.